# div inside div with img overflow issue, (jsfiddle included)

Tags: css, image, html

i have an example of a div inside a div with an img, however overflow doesn't seem to be working any more

```
<td colspan="2" class="headerCell">
    <div id="topback">
        <img id="close" alt="" src="http://customersupport.tikit.com/forum/custom/close_icon.gif" />
        <div id="toptitle">Searching drtgsdf sdfsd sdf er drgdr drtgt ert erter tert er tert ert e...</div>                    
    </div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2EP/14/)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Overflow is not working its ok. What you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2EP/17/

Basically, if you hard-code the `width:383px`, you might as well do it for `#topback`.

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed `width`. That's why it is not working.

Replace `width` with `min-width`.

```
.CSSTableGenerator{min-width: 383px;}
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp2EP/16/)

Comment: Thank you for your time, however I need to have the outermost div a set size 383px as its a popup, is there any solution where i can maintain a static size of 383px?

Comment: Yes, write `overflow:hidden` to `.CSSTableGenerator`. is this what you want?

Comment: Not exactly, basically i just need to be able to fix the width of the outer-most div and have the toptitle div clip text with an eslipse, ie no overflow... who ever thought html could be so demanding